# ShareActionProvider capture before click event?

Tags: android

Is it possible to capture an event BEFORE a ShareActionProvider icon is clicked? For example, once a share icon is clicked, I want to display a dialog box asking the user "Do you really want to share?" and then have the opportunity to cancel the share action. I have tried to put the dialog box into `onShareTargetSelectedListener`, but it won't work. Thanks for any hints.

Comment: Do you have written code of click listener for share?